# X11 error while forwarding disabled on SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg

I have set up an SSH server on one of my personal computers where I have disabled X11 forwarding.

When starting new shell sessions while connected to this server, I keep getting the message

```
xset: unable to open display ""
Unable to connect to X server
```

I have explicitly told SSH to not forward X11 by these settings in `sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding no
X11UseLocalhost no
```

where I connect via `ssh username@my.ip.address` (i.e. without the `-Y` flag).

I do have a configuration for X11 on the computer where the server is hosted, but I don't know if this causes the problem.

How do I fix this error message? There seems to be many issues close to this, but I can't seem to find one where X11 forwarding is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a wild guess that it may have to do with your profile

try this command

`ssh -t user@host bash --noprofile`

also take a look at your `.profile` and `.bashrc` in your home directory. There may be a command in there that is invoking the display

Comment: Thank you! `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` was not the problem, but rather some scripts for setting the input speed of my mouse and keyboard which I had put in `/etc/profile.d`. I have to make sure that these do not get called during remote sessions.